# Incorrect state of the swapped text

Tags: jquery, grails

**Update**

```
 var text = $('a.loveit strong');

    jQuery ( function ( $ ) {


        var loved = false; 

        $('a.loveit').bind('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            loved = !loved; 
            // toggles clicked state so false becomes true.

            if(!loved){
                originalLove();
            }
            else{
                changeLove();
            }
        });

    });

    function originalLove(){

        text.transition({opacity: 0, scale: 0}, 100, 'easeOutBack', function() {

                     $(".icn-heart").toggle();
                      // console.log('LOVE');
                     text.html("LOVE");
                         text.css({
                         color : '#fff',
                         position : 'relative',
                         left : '0'
                     });
                    text.transition({opacity: 1, scale:1}, 500, 'easeOutBack');

                });

    }

    function changeLove(){
            text.transition({opacity: 0, scale: 0}, 100, 'easeOutBack', function() {


                     $(".icn-heart").toggle();
                       // console.log('LOVED');
                     text.html("LOVED!");
                     text.css({
                         color : '#2b7878',
                         position : 'relative',
                         left : '-11px'
                     });

                     text.transition({opacity: 1, scale:1}, 500, 'easeOutBack');

                });
    }
```

The state should have true and false. If click default "heart Love" (white), it should swap to the blue text "Loved". Vice versa. But I couldn't get both working when swapping between texts.

BTW, I am using transit plugin for easeoutback

**Update with HTML in Grails**

```
<g:set var="personal" bean="personalService" />
                               <g:if test="${personal.lovedThis(portfolio.id, session.userId)}">
                               <div class="love-text">
                                <strong style="opacity: 1; transform: scale(1, 1); color: rgb(43, 120, 120); position: relative; left: -11px;">LOVED!</strong>
                                  </g:if>
                                   <g:else>
                                     <i class="icn-heart"></i>
                                     <div class="love-text">
                                     <strong style="opacity: 1; transform: scale(1, 1); color: rgb(255,255,255); position: relative; left: 0;">LOVE</strong>
                                      </g:else>
```

Unable to make Love/Loved stay persist with correct number. If I click and it shows LOVED with '1' on FF and on Chrome, I click again and it shows LOVE with '1' which is wrong. It should be '0'. Also if I click again on different browser, it will not swap text. I am wondering if

```
var loved = false;
```

is the cause?

Appreciate the help

Comment: some html sample could help us, or a live example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @FelipeP - I added in short html sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
var loved = false; 
loved = !loved;
```

In your callback so `loved` will always be explicitly set to false then inverted for every click event. You want to define the loved variable above, before you bind the click, that way it will toggle for each click, back and forth.

You should also declare you `text` variable higher up so the callback functions have access to it.

```
var text = $('a.loveit strong');

jQuery ( function ( $ ) {
    var loved = false; 

    $('a.loveit').bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // toggles clicked state
        loved = !loved; 

        if(!loved) {
            originalLove();
        } else {
            changeLove();
        }
});
```

Comment: yeah you are right I have already figured it out before I saw your answer. awesome. now testing if it works by toggling

Comment: nope it doesn't work right. Although it toggles, the Love and Loved text stay stuck even in toggle state. i think loved = false is not right because grails will check true/false then assign it to loved. and i cant pass the grail variable to js.

Comment: Did you see my update about moving the text variable to a place where your callbacks can use it?

Comment: yes I did and i realize that functions are inside ready(). I move functions and text outside. it looks like it is working, but not sure.

Comment: My apologies, it seems to go wrong after loading page, it would be wrong over again. states are also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your loved declaration :

```
 var loved = false; 
 loved = !loved;
```

loved will always be true because it's initialzed to false everytime you click whatever it states was.

You should declare it outside the event handler.

here's a corrected version without easing : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidonet/wkLAh/)

Comment: it went wrong with states. seems that after loading the page it would screw up states over again